# Can a power strip being turned off and on again damage a computer?

Tags: power-supply, power, desktop, desktop-computer, powerstrip

I have both my computer and monitor plugged into an extension cord and then into a power strip (I've checked, and both the extension cord and the strip can handle the load and have been handling it for a while now). I was trying to plug a charger into a power strip at the end where the switch is to turn the strip off, and I was in a hurry because the device I was trying to charge was very low on battery. In my haste I accidentally pushed down the switch on the power strip just enough for the power strip to turn off briefly then switch back on. My computer restarted, or at least, that's what it seemed like. I didn't notice until I'd plugged in the device on a different wall outlet and came back to see my computer looking like it had just started up even though beforehand I had Chrome and Steam open. I.e, on the desktop and with Skype open (Skype is set to automatically start when I start my computer). At this point, I turned off the computer through the UI and waited about 10 minutes to start it back up (my line of thinking was to do this so it would have fully shut down and started up cleanly). Could this have damaged my computer at all? It still works fine and sounds like it has been, and I haven't seen any corrupted files so far. My computer is an Asus M51AD-B05. [This](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/asus-essentio-desktop-intel-core-i7-12gb-memory-2tb-hard-drive/3026586.p?id=1219086172072) is the exact computer I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OS will recover itself automatically in such cases and informs you with any critical errors that happened , so you don't have to worry much.

You might consider buying an Uninterruptible Power Supply (UPS), it helps a lot with protecting your computer with power problems.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That gives me peace of mind like you wouldn't believe. It didn't tell me of any critical errors or the like or I would've mentioned it, just how it normally looks when the computer's first been started up. I don't think investing in a UPS is necessary at the moment, since I don't usually have power problems where I live, but I'll definitely look into it whenever I have some spare cash!

Comment: The UPS will keep the current steady and safe for your computer , and if the main power is out , you can still save your work and shut the PC in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue something like this would cause is data corruption (if your computer was in the middle of a write operation when the power was cut). Most of the time, however, you probably won't have a problem.

You may want to run [chkdsk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491051.aspx) though, just to make sure.

Comment: Well, I was about to run chkdsk but it told me as soon as I tried starting it that no errors were found on the drive. Should I still run a full chkdsk or is this enough? I'm on Windows 8, by the way. EDIT: To be specific, it said as soon as I clicked "Check" it gave me [this](http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/6155d1337025864-chkdsk-check-drive-errors-windows-8-option-1.jpg) dialogue box (screenshot taken from eightforums, exact same dialogue box except the top refers to C: instead of G:).

Comment: Oh yeah, and because I can't edit a comment twice, the top of the dialogue box also just says "Windows" instead of Windows 7 since I'm on Windows 8.

Comment: @Josh It probably isn't really necessary, but if you are concerned, and have the time, you could run a full chkdsk (maybe leave it running before you go to sleep).

Comment: @Izam Ah, alright. I probably won't, then. I ran the initial check 3 times to be sure and to get the full content of the dialogue box written down (not sure why I didn't screencap it myself at that point, but oh well, I'm a bit paranoid about these sorts of things) just in case and nothing ever came up or changed, so it probably won't be necessary. If I ever come across a corrupted file or something, I will, but otherwise I probably won't unless I have to do something for a couple hours some day. Thanks a bunch!